# Deploying Qt Windows application

Tags: qt, dll, window, windeployqt

I have hard times trying to deploy my windows application to other computer.

Using windeployqt, program run perfectly fine standalone on my machine. Even after renaming Qt Root and project root directory, to ensure the .exe uses bundled .dll's.

Although, app crashes right after startup on any other pc/vm. I've already tried to copy whole bin/plugins/qml/platforms folders to the .exe neighbourhood manually, didn't work.  Here is log dump from x96dbg :

```
    DLL Loaded: 6F240000 C:\Users\iryd\Desktop\data\sceneparsers\gltfsceneimport.dll
INT3 breakpoint "TLS Callback 1 (gltfsceneimport.dll)" at gltfsceneimport.6F251B20 (6F251B20)!
INT3 breakpoint "TLS Callback 2 (gltfsceneimport.dll)" at gltfsceneimport.6F251AD0 (6F251AD0)!
Thread D50 created, Entry: qt5core.68AA9E40
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 1
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 00000000
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000008 DEP Violation
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
First chance exception on 00000000 (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
EXCEPTION_DEBUG_INFO:
           dwFirstChance: 0
           ExceptionCode: C0000005 (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
          ExceptionFlags: 00000000
        ExceptionAddress: 5BFCD9C1
        NumberParameters: 2
ExceptionInformation[00]: 00000000 Read
ExceptionInformation[01]: 00000000 Inaccessible Address
Last chance exception on 5BFCD9C1 (C0000005, EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION)!
```

Where look for the bug?

Comment: What do you mean by ".exe neighbourhood"?

Comment: @MrEricSir Probably that he copied the files next to the .exe in its install folder

Comment: Dropping the .exe file in [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help you find which library(ies) are needed.

Comment: Do you really have `bin/plugins/qml/platforms` under windows? or you mean `$QTBASE/plugins/platforms` ?

Comment: The error was totally unrelated to the deploy method. The machine (VirtualBox) I was testing the program on haven't got a hardware grapchic acceleration, which cause problems.